How to calculate the Area of a sin wave with intersections
I want to generate a sine wave from 2 data points, tmin and tmax. where tmin is where the sin wave starts, and the tmax is the top most point of the sine wave.
Then I want to find where tbase and tlimit intersect with the sine wave created in the previous step.
Example.
C = tlimit
B = tbase

I want to find area's 1 and 2 (as in the example image)

currently, I'm able to calculate the area when tlimit is above tmax and tbase is less than or equal to tmin, just need help with this. here are my existing code but it may be wrong.
Existing Code
const calculateArea = (amplitude, meanTemp, threshold, start, end, steps = 1000) => {
    const dx = (end - start) / steps;
    let area = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        const x = start + (i * dx);
        const y = amplitude * Math.sin(x) + meanTemp;
        if (y > threshold) {
            const areaToAdd = (y - threshold) * dx;
            area += areaToAdd;
        }
    }
    return area;
}

// Called like
const tmean = (tmax + tmin) / 2;
const amplitude = (tmax - tmin) / 2;
const start = 0;
const end = 2 * Math.PI;
const area1 = calculateAreaThreshold(amplitude, tmean, tbase, start, end)
const area2 = calculateAreaThreshold(amplitude, tmean, tlimit, start, end)
return area1 + area2;

Test data (with results that may be wrong)
# Test Data 1
tmin = 5
tmax = 25
tbase = 10
tlimit = 30

current_returned_result = 39.610976908929906

# Test Data 2
tmin = 5
tmax = 25
tbase = 20
tlimit = 30

current_returned_result = 7.527554726471326

# Test Data 3
tmin = 5
tmax = 25
tbase = 15
tlimit = 22

current_returned_result = 24.679341500413543

I've been watching videos from Khan Academy on YT, about AP Calculus but I'm super lost
Update 1
I have tmin, tmax these are the values needed to generate the sine wave. then i have tbase and tlimit which intersect the sine wave.
I want to calculate the area for the blue shaded part labeled 1 and 2.
t is unknown (its the time, horizontal axis) and c^ (c with a circle) is just the y axis.
I only have those 4 values to work with, a 5th value which is the mean such as (tmax + tmin) / 2
Update 2
ChatGPT gave me this, but I don't think this is right at all.
M = (T_max + T_min) / 2
A = (T_max - T_min) / 2
t1 = 12 - (24 / (2 * math.pi)) * math.asin((tbase - M) / A)
t2 = 12 + (24 / (2 * math.pi)) * math.asin((tbase - M) / A)
area_1 = (A * math.cos(math.pi * (t1 - 12) / 12) + M - tbase) * (12 - t1)
area_2 = (A * math.cos(math.pi * (t2 - 12) / 12) + M - tbase) * (t2 - 12)
area = (area_1 + area_2) / 24

Update 3
Reason for getting the areas, I need to calculate these area's for a project at work as its related to GDD (Growing degree days). so the tmin and tmax are min and max values for a day. tbase and tlimit are the are unique to each crop.
The sine wave would start at x = 0 and y = tmin, the peak of the sine wave would reach y = tmax
Update 4
after reviewing the suggested documents / links. and chatting with ChatGPT
I've managed to come up with this function
const calculateSineArea = (tmin, tmax, tbase, tlimit) => {
        const amplitude = (tmax - tmin) / 2;
        const angleBase = Math.asin((tbase - tmin) / amplitude) * (180 / Math.PI);
        const angleLimit = Math.asin((tlimit - tmin) / amplitude) * (180 / Math.PI);
        const areaBase = (Math.PI / 180) * angleBase * amplitude;
        const areaLimit = (Math.PI / 180) * angleLimit * amplitude;
        const finalArea = (areaLimit - areaBase) * amplitude;
        return finalArea;
    } 

but I get 0 returned
here are the few tests I've done
Test 1
// inputs
tmin:5, tmax:25, tbase:10, tlimit:30
// calculated
amplitude:10, angleBase:30.000000000000004, angleLimit:NaN, areaBase:5.23598775598299, areaLimit:NaN, finalArea:NaN

Test 2
// inputs
tmin:5, tmax:25, tbase:20, tlimit:30
// calculated
amplitude:10, angleBase:NaN, angleLimit:NaN, areaBase:NaN, areaLimit:NaN, finalArea:NaN

Test 3
// inputs
tmin:5, tmax:25, tbase:15, tlimit:22
// calculated
amplitude:10, angleBase:90, angleLimit:NaN, areaBase:15.707963267948966, areaLimit:NaN, finalArea:NaN


This seems basic trigonometry, but I have trouble understanding where your tmin and tmax are and what you're trying to calculate. Can you read your text again? Perhaps the image isn't very clear. Is t on the horizontal axis? t for "time" perhaps?

@KIKOSoftware see my update, but yes t is horizontal axis. I haven't worked with math like this in 10+ years, so I've forgotten how to do this.

I think you need integration of your function, which is sin(x) in your case. Then you need to find the intersection points and to get the area, just put the values ∫sin(x) as far as I understand

@mbattaloglu  I don't understand what you mean.

Well, can we agree that the area of 1 and 2 are the same? Then, as mbattaloglu already said, use the integral of sin() which is -cos(). See; Integral of Sin x with an offset.

I think that ChatGPT thinks you're dealing with an analog clock? Quite funny.

@X3R0 So, you draw the sin(x)' graphs. Then, you need to find the intersection points with the tbase and tlimit. Then, calculate the ∫sin(x)dx, which is equal to -cos(x) + c. Finally, you can put the values to to -cos(x) and you can subtract them and you just find the area. (When finding intersection points, you need to solve sin(x) = tbase, find x, and x may have more than 1 solution)

Just read the link @KIKOSoftware suggested, I don't fully grasp the explanation.

@X3R0 Yes, that's what I am saying, with more clear way to explain things.

I also think your question isn't quite clear. Understandable, but it makes it hard to give a definite answer. For instance, where does your sine curve start? This is important. It would be even nicer if you told us why you want to know those areas.

By the way, they are symetric so they are equal to each other. So finding 1 area is enough for you.

@KIKOSoftware see update to question

@mbattaloglu yes, that makes sense, then I only need to find 1 of the areas, which i can just return area * 2

Maybe this table will help you understand the Cosine. tmin is the lowest value of your sine, so that's at 270 degrees. The Cosine is 0.0 there. Then you move forward, say 30 degrees, to 300 and there the Cosine is 0.5 so if you have a sine with an amplitude of 1.0 the area is 0.5. Do that for both B and C, subtract, multiply by amplitude, and you have one area.

I know that's not a full solution, but it might help you understand what you need to do.

@KIKOSoftware its okay, I wasn't really expecting a full solution,  but I have updated my question with a new algo attempt, could you perhaps point out what I'm doing wrong?

I'll have a look. Oh, I forgot to say: A sine wave has, at least, two properties: Amplitude and Period. In your code you use tmin and tmax to define the amplitude, but I see nothing that defines the Period. It it unlikely to be 2*Pi. See: Amplitude, Period, Phase Shift and Frequency.

OK, I looked. I see you got the idea, but I don't see any cosine? It is also useful if you can check your calculation. For instance, the area under a unit sine curve from 0 to 180 degrees has an area of 2. Multiply that by amplitude and period and you know what your result should be for that area. Ref: Why is the area under one hump of a sine curve exactly 2?

@KIKOSoftware could you fix my final function?

No, sorry, I'm still no sure what I would need to calculate. I don't want to give a wrong answer.

i replaced in my function Math.asin with Math.cos and got this tmin:5, tmax:25, tbase:10, tlimit:30, amplitude:10, angleBase:50.28177697059672, angleLimit:-45.902147954690705, areaBase:8.775825618903728, areaLimit:-8.011436155469337, finalArea:167.87261774373064

An arc sine function is the inverse of a sine function. You cannot replace a Math.asin by a Math.cos because the first is an inverse and the second isn't. Math isn't about just trying things out, it is about knowing what you're doing. I understand that that takes longer, and you want to take the easy route, but that just doesn't work here.

@KIKOSoftware I agree

This post has way too many updates. Please just rewrite your post to a single, dedicated question post that states what code you have, what problem that code has, and what debugging/testing you did with it. If you update it and that changes everything, the old question is no longer your question and future visitors just need to read through a whole book just to see whether your problem is their problem too.

How I understand you: If I understood you correctly that's what the curve looks like (here is a interactive desmos graph inccluding the value of the area):

How to make the problem simpler: Then by logic both areas are equal. Substituting the argument t of the sine curve by t + the distance between tmax and the y-axis would give you ... * cos( x ) + ... and the cosine function has axis symmetry to y = 0 aka bot areas are equal.
Code
function calculateArea(start, end, min, max) {
    /* Declare: */
    let tbase = start;
    let tlimit = end;
    let tmin = min;
    let tmax = min;

    /* Define integral bounds: */
    let lowerlimit = Math.asin((tbase - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2));
    let upperlimit = Math.asin((tlimit - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2));

    /* Define integrals: */
    let integralline = tbase * upperlimit - tbase * lowerlimit ;
    let integralsine = -(tmax - tmin) / 2 * Math.cos(upperlimit) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * upperlimit  - (-(tmax - tmin) / 2 * Math.cos(lowerlimit) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * lowerlimit);

    /* Calculate area */
    let A = 2 * Math.abs(integralsine - integralline);
    return A;
}

This code seems gives the same output as desmos. E.g.:
  calculateArea(1, 3.7, -1, 10) == 1.4088853715974081;
 calculateArea(1, 6.5, -1, 8.5) == 6.791808139768918;
calculateArea(-1, 6.5, -1, 8.5) == 13.042250896482566;
...

If you have any questions, just ask it.
Math
What you would have to do
So calculating one area is enough. Using your information the function describing the sine curve would f( x ) = (tmax - tmin) / 2 * sin( x ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2, the upper line would be tlimit and the lower line tbase. The purple are is the difference between the area of sine curve to the x axis and the lower line to the x-axis. These are computable by taking the integral from f^-1( tbase ) to f^-1( tlimit ).
Calculating integral bounds
We have to solve (tmax - tmin) / 2 * sin( x ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 = c for x. Subtract (tmax + tmin) / 2, then divide by (tmax - tmin) / 2 and take the inverse sine function: x = arcsin((c - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)). f^-1( x ) = arcsin((x - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)).
Finding the area
Taking the antiderivative of f( x ) and the lower line. Using the factor rule, sum rule and int sin( x ) dx = -cos( x ) + constant:
int f( x ) dx     = -(tmax - tmin) / 2 * cos( x ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * x + constant
int lower line dx = tbase * x                                             + constant

So the integrals are -(tmax - tmin) / 2 * cos( arcsin((tlimit - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * arcsin((x - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) - -(tmax - tmin) / 2 * cos( arcsin((x - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * arcsin((tbase - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) and tbase * tlimit - tbase * tbase. That one area is equal to their difference and there are two so the sum of the areas A is:
A = 2 * |-(tmax - tmin) / 2 * cos( arcsin((tlimit - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * arcsin((x - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) - -(tmax - tmin) / 2 * cos( arcsin((x - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) ) + (tmax + tmin) / 2 * arcsin((tbase - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) - (tbase * arcsin((tlimit - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)) - tbase * arcsin((tbase - (tmax + tmin) / 2) / ((tmax - tmin) / 2)))|

Why the | ... |? The area can't be negative, so to fix to fix that possible problem we just use the absolute value.

in your code, what is start, and end? is that my tbase and tlimit?

as I'm looking at calculateAreaAboveThreshold = (tmin:number, tmax:number, tbase:number, tlimit:number) => {/*code here*/}

Yes it is. tbase = start and tlimit = end.

const degreesToRadians = (degree) => {
    return degree * (Math.PI / 180);
}
 
// value2 > value1
const calculateArea = (value1, value2) => {
    const radiansValue1 = Math.asin(degreesToRadians(value1));
    const radiansValue2 = Math.asin(degreesToRadians(value2));
        
    // integration of sinx = -cosx
    const resultValue1 = -Math.cos(radiansValue1);
    const resultValue2 = -Math.cos(radiansValue2);
        
    return resultValue2 - resultValue1;
};

This should work. Be careful with the degrees-radians conversion. And the value2 must be greater than value1 othervise you get negative values. (Or just wrap the function call with Math.abs())

how would I add this to my function?

I don't understand what you mean @X3R0
